# Expo initializing unwanted git repo

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native, repository, expo

Is there any way to keep Expo from setting up my git repo automatically? If it's relevant to troubleshooting I'm doing a Reactive Native project. Thank you, any insight or workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean when you say, `keep React Native Expo from setting up my git repo automatically?` Are you talking about new expo projects?

Comment: I've clarified my question, yes it is about Expo. Thank you for your message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I don't see any problem with the Expo git init. The only thing to do is to create a GitHub/Bitbucket/Gitlab etc, repo and add the origin to the Expo project.

Anyway, if you just want to remove the auto git init, I think you'll just need to remove the `.git` folder when you create a new Expo project.

Answer (score 1):

Expo automatically initialized a Git repo in your project for you. You can remove git by running:

```
rm -rf .git
```